# Why UserPasswordEncoderInterface can't be initilized in __construct?

Tags: php, symfony

1. I am trying to do initialize $encoder field in my __construct:

   ```
        use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

        ....
       $private $encoder;

        public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
       {
         $this->$encoder=$encoder;  //line 24
       }
   ```
2. When I do this error is thrown:

   ```
    In UserFixture.php line 24:

    Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class 
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder could not 
    be converted to string
   ```

Comment: You have an extra $

Comment: ... and a second extra $ before `private`

Comment: How did this even work to begin with? That fatal is waaaay after a few other fatals. I'm assuming OP didn't copy the code properly?

Comment: Yep, fixed that. Thank You I must check my code ten times before I ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: Your Class UserPasswordEncoder need a public function __toString(){return (string) 'UserPasswordEncoder';}

Answer (score 0):

Since you inject it via the function parameter, you can already use your encoder on the method, and to need to push it in a private attribut.

What do you want to do with that code ?

=> be carefull, you wrote : $private instead of private